# Continuous use power converter?

Tags: power

I am moving from the US to New Zealand, and I’m trying to figure out what electrical/electronic devices I can take with me. I know I just need an adapter for my 100-240v devices, but my question is about 110v only devices.

There are a ton of converters that I can get on Amazon, but I’m not sure what is safe for continuous use. Everything I’ve read so far says using 240v to 110v converters are fine, but shouldn’t be plugged in at all times. Is that true? Are there converters that are safe to be plugged in all the time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about electric converters than travel,

Comment: @Newton I've never used an electric converter except when traveling.

Comment: just thought the folks at electronics.stackexchange would better tell about the continuous usage

Comment: I have this issue here in Brazil. You need to evaluate the power of the converter. For example, for a refrigerator, you will need some more "strong". One thing that I hear and I am not sure if it is right: when you are using converter, you will spend more energy...

Comment: No need to vote to close this. Give it your best answer, but to the OP - I would recommend asking this on the electronics site where the users could offer a more technical explanation.

Comment: @Andre (and others) ... I am voting to close this... not because it is or is not travel related, but because the purpose behind the need is moving from one country to the next... which is [expatriates.se] charter.

Comment: @CGCampbell I’ve never even heard of that site before now. Fair enough, but would it not be better to suggest that to the OP and let him delete this post and ask again?

Comment: @Andre Please read both the question and answers at [Migration path between Travel and Expatriates](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/migration-path-between-travel-and-expatriates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't recommended that you use any such power converter for continuous use.  They are intended for shorter-term use only.  They are also much less efficient than power supplies and devices designed for the higher voltage to begin with.

Most devices with external power supplies can be solved by buying power supplies for the New Zealand voltage.  This will likely be less expensive than a voltage converter would cost.

Some devices like hair dryers, curling irons, toasters, etc. draw large amounts of power and it will make more sense to sell your US equipment in the States, and buy new devices in New Zealand.

Comment: Hair dryers usually have a 220V/110V knob somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to convert voltage for long term use I would reccomend an isolating transformer with appropriate ratings. Note that most transformers have two ratings, a continuous rating and an intermittant rating.

I reccommend an isolating transformer because with an autotransformer if the "neutral" connection fails under light load you can see the input voltage on the output.

In the UK we get "Yellow brick" transformers used on construction sites which are 240V to 110V isolating transformers and are reasonablly affordable.  For example https://www.screwfix.com/p/portable-transformer-with-2-output-sockets-3kva/84144 which has an intermittant rating of 3KVA and a continuous rating of 1.5KVA. No idea if you can get anything similar in NZ.

Honestly though it has to be a pretty special appliance for it to be worth it.